# How do I tie entries from sys.dm_exec_sessions to what database the query is executing in?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using sys.dm_exec_sessions to get ongoing queries in an instance. How can I find what db the query is executing in?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Currently running queries in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767676/currently-running-queries-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join `sys.dm_exec_sessions` to `sys.dm_exec_requests` on `session_id`. The latter has a field `database_id`. Here's a snippet to get you started.

```
select
    RequestDBName = db_name(r.database_id),
    ObjectId = st.objectid,
    ObjectDbName = db_name(st.dbid),
    ObjectSchemaName = object_schema_name(st.objectid, st.dbid),
    ObjectName = object_name(st.objectid, st.dbid),
    SqlText = st.text,
    CurrentlyExecutingStmt =
        substring
        (
            st.text, 
            ( r.statement_start_offset / 2 ) + 1, 
            ( 
                ( 
                    iif
                    (
                        r.statement_end_offset <= 0,
                        datalength(st.text),
                        r.statement_end_offset 
                    ) - r.statement_start_offset 
                ) / 2 
            ) + 1
        ),
    *
from sys.dm_exec_requests r
inner join sys.dm_exec_sessions xs
    on r.session_id = xs.session_id
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) s
```